# How can I add the local administrators group to SQL in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012. I would like to grant all local administrators (the box is not on a domain) sysadmin rights to SQL Server, but am having difficulty.

I can create a login and assign BUILTIN\Administrators, but it does not actually allow administrator users to connect. It only works if I assign specific users as ServerName\UserName.

Comment: Perhaps it's UAC.  Can the users connect locally if they use "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Look at these answers here and see if this will help you any: http://serverfault.com/questions/338222/how-to-allow-the-local-administrator-to-have-access-to-sql-server#

Comment: I agree with @DanGuzman as the local admins connecting will need the authorization token which requires choosing run as admin even if you have "turned uac off" as that only disabled the prompt and doesn't actually turn it off.

Comment: Is it in a clustered or stand-alone environment?  It does matter.

Comment: You guys are great. Ran as administrator and it worked. Thanks!